# How to register multiple values in a variable?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to display all the pair numbers in a loop that goes from 1 to 100 and increments 1 each time. I try to display the pair numbers like they would in this "if" code block.

```cs
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

But I want to save these in a string called "losPares", which I attempt to do display in this way:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var counter = 0;
    var losPares = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            counter++;
            losPares = i;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("hay " + counter + " numeros pares.");
    Console.WriteLine("estos son " + losPares);
}
```

Which is kinda weird. In the first code example the console will print out all the pair numbers. In the second one it will only print the last of them, 98. I don't really know what to do, tried creating an array instead of a variable but when I try to store "i" in it i get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'int[]'

aAd if i try to cast "i" as a string when losPares is an array instead of a variable, like this:

```cs
int[] losPares = new int[100];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        counter++;
        losPares = Convert.ToBase64CharArray(i);
    }
```

I get the following error.

> CS1501    No overload for method 'ToBase64CharArray' takes 1 arguments

I don't really know what to do. Thanks a bunch for reading!

Comment: As per my understanding below are my takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An integer will only have 1 value and cannot have multiple values at the same time. If you want to keep track of all the values from the loop, you will have to save all the values in a collection / list or an array. Following example shows how to save them in a List.

```
var counter = 0;
var losPares = new List<int>();
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        counter++;
        losPares.Add(i);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("hay " + counter + " numeros pares.");
Console.WriteLine("estos son " + string.Join(" ", losPares));
```

You can create a list of ints (losPares) and then display that at the end. What you are doing is assigning a value to `losPares` and then overriding it again and again until the last iteration in you loop. That is why your losPares always have the last value.

Answer (score 1):

Your console is printing last element because you are assigning value of `i` to `losPares` in your sencond code snippet. This assignment operator assinging value of `i` to `losPares` in each iteration where `i % 2` condition is satisfied.

Instead of assigning value to integer, use [List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netcore-3.1) to store `i` and at the end of for loop print all elements from list.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var losPares = List<int>();
    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            counter++;
            //Below line was executing everytime and in each execution this line was assigning value of i to losPares
            //losPares = i; 
            losPares.Add(i);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("hay " + counter + " numeros pares.");
    Console.WriteLine("estos son " + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, losPares));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding below are my takes. First one is printing all values because the printing part is inside the loop but in second both print statements are outside the for loop block because of which it stores the last value of loop and display it.

You can create a string variable and append all the numbers to that string.

string temp = ''; and then in for loop you can do something like temp+=i + ' '; It is better to use string builder because of immutable property of string.

If you want to use array. Below is the way to assign values in a array.

int[] losPares = new int[100];

In a for loop you can use losPares[i] = i; This will fill your array.